# Spring Data JPA save only if doesnt exist

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I found a code in project. It looks like:

```
private <S, T extends BaseEntity<S>> void saveIfNotExist(T baseEntity, JpaRepository<T, S> jpaRepository) {
        jpaRepository
                .findById(baseEntity.getId())
                .orElseGet(() -> jpaRepository.save(baseEntity));
}
```

As far as i understand, this method will not save/update entity in database, if entity already exists.

`BaseEntity`:

```
public interface BaseEntity<T> {
    T gettId();
}
```

Implementation:

```
@Entity
@Table(..)
public class Account implements BaseEntity<String> {

    @Id
    private String login;
    
    @Column(name = "is_archive")
    private Boolean isArchive;
   

    public String getId() {
        return this.getLogin();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Integer>
```

My question is: how can i replace this method with common Spring Data JPA realisation (save only if not exists, don't update)?

Comment: What is the problem with the method `saveIfNotExist` ?

Comment: For example, JpaRepository as param. It's really not clean to read. And this code used in many services for saving into database operations.

Comment: why complicate things. Cant you just use boolean exists = repository.existsById(searchId) method and then save based on exists flag ?

Comment: I did a tutorial on some spring application and this was covered I think it is explained in this video 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBSwPBZ5u3k&list=PLXy8DQl3058Nju76-H12i58my0SId75v5&index=4

Anyway it is in abstract crudl service updateEntity method